# Jquery deferred - put off a function invocation before previous function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm looking for returning objects via promises, I'm looking to make sure that one asynchronous function is fully complete before executing another function.

```
$.when(firstFunction()).done(secondFunction());
```

is something like this possible ?

Comment: And what does those async functions contain, or more importantly what do they return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though because ordinary functions don't return deferred objects, you'll need to make the deferred object yourself.

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred;
dfd.done(secondFunction);
firstFunction();
```

...then have `firstFunction()` resolve `dfd` (via `dfd.resolve()`) at the appropriate point. So if `firstFunction` contains an AJAX request, say, it might look like this:

```
function firstFunction() {
    $.get('some/file.txt').done(function() { dfd.resolve(); });
}
```

Comment: +1, but would be much more intuitive if `firstFunction` creates the Deferred and return it, so it can be called as `firstFunction().done(secondFunction)`

Comment: @MartinJespersen - yes, good call, though not everyone loves the chaining pattern.